# Laravel & Vuejs Integration - Vuejs mixins

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, sweetalert2

I'm trying to create a `mixin` to handle my `sweetalerts2` logic. Now, i've created a mixin named `sweetAlerts.js` inside a folder: `assets/js/misins` and i wrote the next block of code inside of it:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2'

export default {
  methods: {
    $sAlert(data) {
      swal(data)
    },
    $sToast(data) {
      swal.mixin(data)
    },
  }
};
```

Then i've imported it on my `app.js` file like this:

```
import sweetAlerts from './mixins/sweetAlerts'
Vue.mixin(sweetAlerts)
```

The problem is that methods like this one doesn't work:

```
methods: {
    launchAlert() {
        this.$sAlert(data)
    }
}
```

I know that `sweetalerts2` works just fine because i've tested it inside my application. The main problem is that i can't create a mixin with all the alerts logic to implement it on any component i want.

Is there a solution for it ?

Comment: Any error output in your browser's console?

Comment: Well your example isnt passing a data arg to `launchAlert` or using `this.data.whatever`.

Comment: There is no error in console. Also, yes, there is no data in my example to simplify things but i can add the real code if you want to but as I said, the same data i'm passing right now used to work when i wasn't trying to implement the alerts as mixins.

Comment: Well, it works now (for some random reason) so i will close this question. Thanks!